# Meta viewport scale not working - responsive

Tags: scale

I have inserted:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

into the header of my website, but it is not disabling the SCALE function on my macbook (haven't tested elsewhere yet) like it should be. I have tried the exact same code that is used in another theme I used before but it still doesn't work.

What could be the reason for this and how do I fix it?

Comment: I thought meta view-port was more for zoom features on mobile devices rather than scrolling up and down pages, is the theme you are looking at either positioning the `<body>` absolutely or hiding the overflow to stop the scroll?

Comment: Sorry, I meant scale not scroll. I think you are right, I'm new to view-port so excuse me. I have checked on my iphone and it has disabled the zoom, which is good.

I guess there is a different setting to disable the zoom on all devices? (computer screens)

Comment: If the browser's User Agent chooses to ignore the meta tag, there ain't a simple solution. See [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) for a relatively complete list of options, but I'd highly advise against attempting to force non-zoom across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use responsivem.js  It would require you to specify everything in em, but you could write a script to replace all the px with em.  check it out.